# Single referrer traffic .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, referrer, traffic

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}!(.*)ocean-leecher.net(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}!(.*)blindtext.info(.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}!(.*)yourdomain.com(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

This code accept 3 referrer traffic to all pages of main domain.

Is there any way to make this code valid for just `maindomain.com/thankyoupage.php`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/thankyoupage.php$
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(ocean-leecher\.net|blindtext\.info|yourdomain\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^thankyoupage\.php$ - [F,NC,L]
```